# I updated rstudio and when i open new rmarkdown file i get the message

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

```
1.digest.0.6.25 is required but .0.6.15 is available 

2. evaluate0.13 is required but 0.11 is available 
3. ..................... +
4. ..................... +
5. markdown 2,0 is required but 1.0 is available+
6. .................................+
7. ....................................................+

8. Check that getOption(repos) refers to a CRAN repository that contains the  needed package versions
```

Comment: update your packages via ```update.packages()```